# Finding all programs which are using Java on windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, java, jvm

I am looking for a way with which I can find any and all programs which are using Java on a windows server. Is there a cmd command or something similar which would give me a list of all programs using java? Thanks

**Edit:** I am basically about to remove Java from the server but before I do that I am trying make sure there is nothing on the server which is using Java.

Comment: I don't think so. A program using java could be anything from `.exe` to `.jar` or some webapp or whatever. The only way I could think of would be to run some software inventory and check every entry manually. But even that is not 100% sure.

Comment: whats a software inventory? @Lenniey

Comment: A program that inventories the software on your server, ususally based on some form of filter. E.g. SCCM has a software inventory feature in which you can define a pattern to search for: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/core/clients/manage/inventory/configure-software-inventory

Comment: Could also be needed for a browser accessing a web site. These are quite rare now, but I believe Remedy was one example.

Comment: @GregAskew I am not sure what you are trying to say, can please provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

Identifying running applications using java is possible in at least 2 ways i think :

- [jps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) tool in your JDK
- [Java Usage Tracker](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/usage-tracker/overview/)

For Non-running application it's quite impossible without any kind of inventory.

Comment: Please share a little more details about how it can be done with either jps or java usage tracker